# Symbol prints wrong value

Tags: action, symbol-name, asset

I have a method like this:

```
void token::test(asset qty) {
    print("\n", qty);
    print("\n", qty.symbol);
}
```

and the output I get is something like this:

> 10.00000000 XXX
>
> 8,XXX3

why the 3?  I have the value XXX stored in a table but the lookup fails because apparently it's looking for XXX3.  what is wrong with this picture?

-- **Edit I** --

I also see odd output like:

> 10.00 TTX
>
> 2,TTX.00 TTX3

I don't understand what's going on???

-- **Edit II** --

this gets more bizarre.  if I pass "10.00 USDC", I get back:

> 3,USDCu000b4

Comment: When do you see the odd output in comparison to the "normal" output?

Comment: Maybe try changing the second print statement to have a comma between the newline and the symbol too, see if its some kind of bug to do with that

Comment: that was a typo in the post.  the code has a comma

Comment: Ah ok. What about using `qty.symbol.code().to_string()`, does that work?

Comment: that prints `USD` only

Comment: It's a bug in `eosio::symbol::print`. I sent PR about this issue.

Comment: fi that's all it is I need to do further testing as for why my index queries are failing...

Comment: if you want to post your respose as an answer I'll tag it and let this close

Comment: @conr2d can you post a link to the PR please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug. `eosio::symbol::print` needs to call `eosio::printl`, but calls `eosio::print` by mistake. The PR on following link fixes this:

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/pull/552

Comment: Thanks for linking the PR from Github!